# copy certain file patterns to another folder

Tags: windows, vbscript, copy

Good afternoon, I wish to have a script that will look for all files with the name pattern LCP-??? and/or FSA-??? in c:\streetweeper and copy them to D:\java\temp\sz-files.
This script will run on startup.

I found a vbscript which has very similar functionality yet it uses a text file to read the files which need to be copied. can anyone help me transform this script to function as described above?

thanks for your time, the script is below:

```
Option Explicit

'The source path for the copy operation.
Const strSourceFolder = "c:\streetweeper"

'The target path for the copy operation.
Const strTargetFolder = "D:\java\temp\sz-files"

'The list of files to copy. Should be a text file with one file on each row. No paths -    just file name.
Const strFileList = "C:\filelist.txt"

'Should files be overwriten if they already exist? TRUE or FALSE.
Const blnOverwrite = FALSE

Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading = 1
Dim objFileList
Set objFileList = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileList, ForReading, False)

Dim strFileToCopy, strSourceFilePath, strTargetFilePath
On Error Resume Next
Do Until objFileList.AtEndOfStream
'Read next line from file list and build filepaths
strFileToCopy = objFileList.Readline
strSourceFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(strSourceFolder, strFileToCopy)
strTargetFilePath = objFSO.BuildPath(strTargetFolder, strFileToCopy)

'Copy file to specified target folder.
Err.Clear
objFSO.CopyFile strSourceFilePath, strTargetFilePath, blnOverwrite
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    'File copied successfully

Else
    'Error copying file
    Wscript.Echo "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & "). Copying " & strFileToCopy
End If
Loop
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but is there a reason you don't want to do this with a shell/batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `copystuff.cmd`

```
REM The following statement will have no effect if the directory does exist.
mkdir D:\java\temp\sz-files

XCOPY /Y /E c:\streetweeper\LCP-*.* D:\java\temp\sz-files

IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO COPYNEXT
GOTO END

:COPYNEXT
XCOPY /Y /E c:\streetweeper\FSA-*.* D:\java\temp\sz-files

IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO DELETEFILES
GOTO End

:DELETEFILES
DEL /Q LCP-*.*
DEL /Q FSA-*.*

:End
```

OR

```
REM The following statement will have no effect if the directory does exist.
mkdir D:\java\temp\sz-files

MOVE /Y C:\StreetSweeper\LCP-*.* D:\Java\Temp\sz-files
MOVE /Y C:\StreetSweeper\FSA-*.* D:\Java\Temp\sz-files
```

Stuff in the startup folder of your start menu and you're good to go!

Comment: Ok it can be a .cmd script however can it be modified so it does a move instead of a copy?

also can there be error checking and what if the folder D:\java\temp\sz-files does not exist will it create the folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is a VBScript file that copies file patterns using regular expressions. The Directory functionality is written by [Christian d'Heureuse](http://www.source-code.biz.)

I did not do argument parsing in full detail. So the script will only work, if source and destiation patterns contain an `*`.

The call should look like:

`cscript myscript.vbs "C:\temp\filesToCopy_*.txt" "D:\temp\newName_*.txd"`

```
'  ___      _   _                ___               
' | _ \__ _| |_| |_ ___ _ _ _ _ / __|___ _ __ _  _ 
' |  _/ _` |  _|  _/ -_) '_| ' \ (__/ _ \ '_ \ || |
' |_| \__,_|\__|\__\___|_| |_||_\___\___/ .__/\_, |
'                                       |_|   |__/ 
' Copy files using patterns
' any given String is split into three parts {part1}{*}{part3}
' the replacement String is used in the same pattern to replace the three parts 
' (c) m.wallner-novak
'
' vbCopyFile
' Usage cscript vbCopyFile.vbs {Source} {Destination}
'

Option Explicit

Main

'''
' Main Procedure
'
Sub Main

    dim SourcePattern 
    dim DestPattern 
    dim sFile

    if Wscript.Arguments.count = 2 then

        SourcePattern = WScript.arguments(0)
        DestPattern = WScript.arguments(1)

        Dim a
        a = ListDir(SourcePattern)

        If UBound(a) = -1 then
            WScript.Echo "No files found with specified source path:"
            WScript.Echo SourcePattern
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim FileName
        dim regEx
        Set regEx = new regexp  'Create the RegExp object
        dim sPattern

        sPattern = SourcePattern
        sPattern = replace(sPattern,"\","\\")
        sPattern = replace(sPattern,".","\.")
        sPattern = replace(sPattern,"*",")(.*)(")
        sPattern = "(" & sPattern & ")"

        dim part1
        dim part3
        dim pos1

        pos1 = instr(DestPattern,"*")

        if pos1>0 then
            part1 = left(DestPattern,pos1-1)
            part3 = mid(DestPattern,pos1+1,999)
        end if

        regEx.Pattern = sPattern
        regEx.IgnoreCase = True

        Dim Fso
        Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")        

        on error resume next
        For Each FileName In a
            WScript.Echo "copying """ & FileName & """ to """ & regEx.Replace(FileName, part1 & "$2" & part3) & """"
            Fso.CopyFile FileName, regEx.Replace(FileName, part1 & "$2" & part3)

            if err.number <> 0 then
                Wscript.echo "ERROR #" & err.number & vbcrlf & err.Description
                exit sub
            end if
        Next

    else
        WScript.echo "Wrong number of arguments"
        WScript.echo Wscript.ScriptName & " SourcePattern DestinationPattern"
        WScript.echo "SourcePattern and DestinationPattern are {part1}{*}{part3}"
        WScript.echo "Example: Hello*.exe Hello_World*_prefix.exe"
        WScript.echo " will copy Hello123.exe to Hello_World123_prefix.exe"
    end if

end sub

'''
' Test program for the ListDir function.
' Lists file names using wildcards.
'
' Author:  Christian d'Heureuse (www.source-code.biz)
' License: GNU/LGPL (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html)
'
' Changes:
' 2006-01-19 Extended to handle the special case of filter masks
'            ending with a ".". Thanks to Dave Casey for the hint.
Sub Main2
   Dim Path
   Select Case WScript.Arguments.Count
      Case 0: Path = "*.*"             ' list current directory
      Case 1: Path = WScript.Arguments(0)
      Case Else: WScript.Echo "Invalid number of arguments.": Exit Sub
      End Select
   Dim a: a = ListDir(Path)
   If UBound(a) = -1 then
      WScript.Echo "No files found."
      Exit Sub
      End If
   Dim FileName
   For Each FileName In a
      WScript.Echo FileName
      Next
   End Sub

' Returns an array with the file names that match Path.
' The Path string may contain the wildcard characters "*"
' and "?" in the file name component. The same rules apply
' as with the MSDOS DIR command.
' If Path is a directory, the contents of this directory is listed.
' If Path is empty, the current directory is listed.
' Author: Christian d'Heureuse (www.source-code.biz)
Public Function ListDir (ByVal Path)
   Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   If Path = "" then Path = "*.*"
   Dim Parent, Filter
   if fso.FolderExists(Path) then      ' Path is a directory
      Parent = Path
      Filter = "*"
     Else
      Parent = fso.GetParentFolderName(Path)
      If Parent = "" Then If Right(Path,1) = ":" Then Parent = Path: Else Parent = "."
      Filter = fso.GetFileName(Path)
      If Filter = "" Then Filter = "*"
      End If
   ReDim a(10)
   Dim n: n = 0
   Dim Folder: Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Parent)
   Dim Files: Set Files = Folder.Files
   Dim File
   For Each File In Files
      If CompareFileName(File.Name,Filter) Then
         If n > UBound(a) Then ReDim Preserve a(n*2)
         a(n) = File.Path
         n = n + 1
         End If
      Next
   ReDim Preserve a(n-1)
   ListDir = a
 End Function

Private Function CompareFileName (ByVal Name, ByVal Filter) ' (recursive)
   CompareFileName = False
   Dim np, fp: np = 1: fp = 1
   Do
      If fp > Len(Filter) Then CompareFileName = np > len(name): Exit Function
      If Mid(Filter,fp) = ".*" Then    ' special case: ".*" at end of filter
         If np > Len(Name) Then CompareFileName = True: Exit Function
         End If
      If Mid(Filter,fp) = "." Then     ' special case: "." at end of filter
         CompareFileName = np > Len(Name): Exit Function
         End If
      Dim fc: fc = Mid(Filter,fp,1): fp = fp + 1
      Select Case fc
         Case "*"
            CompareFileName = CompareFileName2(name,np,filter,fp)
            Exit Function
         Case "?"
            If np <= Len(Name) And Mid(Name,np,1) <> "." Then np = np + 1
         Case Else
            If np > Len(Name) Then Exit Function
            Dim nc: nc = Mid(Name,np,1): np = np + 1
            If Strcomp(fc,nc,vbTextCompare)<>0 Then Exit Function
         End Select
      Loop
End Function

Private Function CompareFileName2 (ByVal Name, ByVal np0, ByVal Filter, ByVal fp0)
   Dim fp: fp = fp0
   Dim fc2
   Do                                  ' skip over "*" and "?" characters in filter
      If fp > Len(Filter) Then CompareFileName2 = True: Exit Function
      fc2 = Mid(Filter,fp,1): fp = fp + 1
      If fc2 <> "*" And fc2 <> "?" Then Exit Do
      Loop
   If fc2 = "." Then
      If Mid(Filter,fp) = "*" Then     ' special case: ".*" at end of filter
         CompareFileName2 = True: Exit Function
         End If
      If fp > Len(Filter) Then         ' special case: "." at end of filter
         CompareFileName2 = InStr(np0,Name,".") = 0: Exit Function
         End If
      End If
   Dim np
   For np = np0 To Len(Name)
      Dim nc: nc = Mid(Name,np,1)
      If StrComp(fc2,nc,vbTextCompare)=0 Then
         If CompareFileName(Mid(Name,np+1),Mid(Filter,fp)) Then
            CompareFileName2 = True: Exit Function
            End If
         End If
      Next
   CompareFileName2 = False
 End Function
```

---